# How Can I Change DataTransfer Data in Drop event

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I have a draggable element:

```html
<div class="draggable"> Draggable </div>
```

I'm setting the `dataTransfer` data on the `dragStart` event:

```js
onDragStart(event) {
   event.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', 'data')
}
```

I want to process this data depending on where the user drops it:

```js
onDropToReplaceArea(event) {
   event.preventDefault();

   // Replacing the dropped area content
}

onDropToContentEditableArea(event) {
   // I don't want to the "preventDefault" function! Otherwise, I cannot insert the element to where the cursor is. I exactly want what if I set this in the "dragStart" function.
   event.dataTransfer.setData('text/html', '<span>Users dropped me to the wherever they want!</span>')
}
```

Unfortunately, `dataTransfer.setData` does not work when I call it in the `drop` or `dragOver` events. Is there any way to achieve this?